# Monitoring BizTalk Server Ports with Auto-Healing capabilities with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, biztalk

First try script will read exception RL name not equal "FTP_XML"

```
[ARRAY]$ReceiveLocations = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_ReceiveLocation -Namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -Filter '(IsDisabled = True)' |
                           Where-Object { $_.Name -ne "FTP_XML" }
$ReceiveLocations
```

Second try script will not read exception RLS name not equal "FTP_XML", "RL2" and give all Disabled RLS

```
[ARRAY]$ReceiveLocations = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_ReceiveLocation -Namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -Filter '(IsDisabled = True)' |
                           Where-Object { $_.Name -ne "FTP_XML", "RL2" }
$ReceiveLocations
```

How can I include exception list more then what we have as exception?

OR

We can read the variable as below from text file, but it also not reading from TEXT file (all list of RLs start with new line) and gives me all disabled RLs.

```
[ARRAY]$exceptionList = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Dipen\Desktop \Exception_List.txt
[ARRAY]$ReceiveLocations = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_ReceiveLocation -Namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -Filter '(IsDisabled = True)' |
                           Where-Object { $_.Name -ne "$exceptionList" }
$ReceiveLocations
```

Comment: you should be using get-content instead of get-childitem for reading file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `-ne` will check if a single value is not the same as a list of values, which obviously will always evaluate to true. The operator for checking if a given value does not exist in a list of values is `-notcontains` (`$list -notcontains $value`). On PowerShell v3 and newer you can also use the operator `-notin` (`$value -notin $list`), which probably feels more natural to most users.

```
$ReceiveLocations = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_ReceiveLocation -Namespace  'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -Filter '(IsDisabled = True)' |
                    Where-Object { 'FTP_XML', 'RL2' -notcontains $_.Name }
```

To read a list of values from a file use `Get-Content`, as [Abhijith pk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205282/monitoring-biztalk-server-ports-with-auto-healing-capabilities-with-powershell#comment69613224_41205282) already mentioned in the comments to your question.

```
$exceptionList = Get-Content C:\Users\Dipen\Desktop \Exception_List.txt
$ReceiveLocations = Get-WmiObject MSBTS_ReceiveLocation -Namespace 'root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer' -Filter '(IsDisabled = True)' |
                    Where-Object { $exceptionList -notcontains $_.Name }
```

Note that you must not put the list variable in quotes.

Comment: I have certain RL name on text file that I don't want to add into $ReceiveLocations using Where-Object { $_.Name -ne "$exceptionList" }. NOT EQUALS

Comment: Or we can specify RLs name into variable that's can be excluded during process!

Comment: Use `-notcontains` instead of `-contains`. You seriously were not able to deduct that from the documentation I referenced?

Comment: Thanks you @Ansgar Wiechers